# How to share external image in custom listview?

Tags: android, listview

I have created a custom listview that is handled by a custom adapter. Each item in this list displays an image and a share button. The images are loaded from external sources with ion. This works fine.

Now I want to share the image when the user clicks on the button. While I'm able to share text, etc. I'm not able to share these external images, even after implementing this code: [Sharing Remote Images](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sharing-Content-with-Intents#sharing-remote-images)

Two things:

- I'm new to android so I might be using the setTag/getTag completely wrong
- `if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable)` is false, but I don't know why or how to fix this

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated!

This is the code from my adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        //brand new
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.contentImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contentImageView);
        holder.contentLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contentLabel);
        holder.contentShareButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contentShareButton);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Content content = mContents[position];

    Ion.with(mContext)
            .load(content.getSrc()) //the external image url
            .intoImageView(holder.contentImageView);

    holder.contentLabel.setText(content.getTitle());

    holder.contentShareButton.setTag(holder.contentImageView);
    holder.contentShareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ImageView ivImage = (ImageView) v.getTag();

            //ImageView ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivResult);
            // Get access to the URI for the bitmap
            Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(ivImage);
            if (bmpUri != null) {
                // Construct a ShareIntent with link to image
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
                shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                // Launch sharing dialog for image
                mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
            } else {
                Log.i("test", "Sharing failed, handler error.");
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

// Returns the URI path to the Bitmap displayed in specified ImageView
public Uri getLocalBitmapUri(ImageView imageView) {
    // Extract Bitmap from ImageView drawable
    Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bmp = null;

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable){
        bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    } else {
        Log.i("test", "is null");
        return null;
    }
    // Store image to default external storage directory
    Uri bmpUri = null;
    try {
        File file =  new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.close();
        bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmpUri;
}
```

Comment: You could have been as friendly to explain your code first. You are extracting a Bitmap from an imageview first and save that as PNG to file. After that you want to share that image file. Moreover you did not tell where in your code things go wrong.

Comment: Isn't Ion also saving the downloaded images to file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding these four lines to the `getLocalBitmapUri`-function got it working for me:

```
bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
drawable.draw(canvas);
```

And here is the complete function with the updated code:

```
// Returns the URI path to the Bitmap displayed in specified ImageView
public Uri getLocalBitmapUri(ImageView imageView) {
    // Extract Bitmap from ImageView drawable
    Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bmp = null;

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable){
        bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    } else {
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
    }
    // Store image to default external storage directory
    Uri bmpUri = null;
    try {
        File file =  new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.close();
        bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmpUri;
}
```